# Finding two documents in MongoDB that share a key value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a large collection of documents in MongoDB, each one of those documents has a key called "name", and another key called "type". I would like to find two documents with the *same name* and *different types*, a simple MongoDB counterpart of

```
SELECT ...
FROM table AS t1, table AS t2
WHERE t1.name = t2.name AND t1.type <> t2.type
```

I can imagine that one can do this using aggregation: however, the collection is very large, processing it will take time and I'm looking just for one pair of such documents.

Comment: Are they two different collections ? - `$or` is the operator - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/ - Your question SQL example hint's that they are 2 collections, but your opening line says 'a large collection of documents' meaning one collection.

Comment: @RobSedgwick: it is one collection; in SQL I'm simply using the same collection (table) twice *as if* these were two collections (tables). `$or` does not seem to work as I need to compare pairs of documents rather than to apply a disjunctive condition to a value.

Comment: okay, so you need something like -  `db.collectionname.find({ $or: [ { name:"namevalue" }, { type:"typevalue" } ] }` ?

Comment: @RobSedgwick: I do not know which value the name should have, I only know that it should be shared by two different documents. Can I somehow indicate a variable in "namevalue"? How can I state that the type values are different?

Comment: Making sure you have set indexes on 'type' and 'name' `db.collectionname.ensureIndex( { type: 1, name: 1 } )` - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-compound-index/#index-create-compound-index

Comment: yes I understand now. $exists looks like what you need ? - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/ ? In a combo with $or or $where most likely

Comment: 'one pair of such documents' - so using `findOne(` also ?

Comment: All those operations seem to assume that the truth value (= whether the document should be included in the result or not) can be determined based on the document itself, which is not the case for the query I'm trying to write.

Comment: There's nothing you can do in a `find` query to access more than one doc at a time, so this will have to be done using `aggregate` (maybe) or `mapReduce`.  But it won't be simple or fast as Mongo's just not well suited to this type of query.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help Alexander. Probably me not getting your question  clearly

Comment: @RobSedgwick: no, the database simply has a key called "type" which is not related to BSON types.

Comment: Nonetheless there is a way to reproduce the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I stand by by comments that I don't think the way you are phrasing your question is actually related to a specific problem you have, I will go someway to explain the idiomatic SQL way in a MongoDB type of solution. I stand on that your actual solution would be different but you haven't presented us with that problem, but only SQL.

So consider the following documents as a sample set, removing _id fields in this listing for clarity:

```js
{ "name" : "a", "type" : "b" }
{ "name" : "a", "type" : "c" }
{ "name" : "b", "type" : "c" }
{ "name" : "b", "type" : "a" }
{ "name" : "a", "type" : "b" }
{ "name" : "b", "type" : "c" }
{ "name" : "f", "type" : "e" }
{ "name" : "z", "type" : "z" }
{ "name" : "z", "type" : "z" }
```

If we ran the SQL presented over the same data we would get this result:

```
a|b
a|c
a|c
b|c
b|a
b|a
a|b
b|c
```

We can see that 2 documents do not match, and then work out the logic of the SQL operation. So the other way of saying it is "Which documents given a key of "name" **do** have more than **one** possible value in the key "type".

Given that, taking a mongo approach, we can query for the items that **do not** match the given condition. So effectively the **reverse** of the result:

```js
db.sample.aggregate([

    // Store unique documents grouped by the "name"
    {$group: { 
        _id: "$name",
        comp: {
            $addToSet: { 
                name:"$name",
                type: "$type" 
            }
        } 
    }},

    // Unwind the "set" results
    {$unwind: "$comp"},

    // Push the results back to get the unique count
    // *note* you could not have done this with alongside $addtoSet
    {$group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        comp: {
            $push: { 
                name: "$comp.name",
                type: "$comp.type" 
            }
        },
        count: {$sum: 1} 
    }},

    // Match only what was counted once
    {$match: {count: 1}},

    // Unwind the array
    {$unwind: "$comp"},

    // Clean up to "name" and "type" only
    {$project: { _id: 0, name: "$comp.name", type: "$comp.type"}}

])
```

This operation will yield the results:

```js
{ "name" : "f", "type" : "e" }
{ "name" : "z", "type" : "z" }
```

Now in order to get the same result as the SQL query we would take those results and channel them into another query:

```js
db.sample.find({$nor: [{ name: "f", type: "e"},{ name: "z", type: "z"}] })
```

Which arrives as the final matching result:

```js
{ "name" : "a", "type" : "b" }
{ "name" : "a", "type" : "c" }
{ "name" : "b", "type" : "c" }
{ "name" : "b", "type" : "a" }
{ "name" : "a", "type" : "b" }
{ "name" : "b", "type" : "c" }
```

So this will work, however the one thing that may make this impractical is where the number of documents being *compared* is very large, we hit a working limit on compacting those results down to an array.

It also suffers a bit from the use of a **negative** in the final find operation which would force a scan of the collection. But in all fairness the same could be said of the SQL query that uses the same **negative** premise.

### Edit

Of course what I did not mention is that if the result set goes the other way around and you are matching **more** results in the excluded items from the aggregate, then just reverse the logic to get the keys that you want. Simply change $match as follows:

```js
{$match: {$gt: 1}}
```

And that will be the result, maybe not the actual documents but it is a result. So you don't need another query to match the negative cases.

And, ultimately this was my fault because I was so focused on the idiomatic translation that I did not **read** the last line in your question, where to **do** say that you were looking for **one** document.

Of course, **currently** if that result size is larger than 16MB then you are stuck. At least until the **2.6** release, where the results of aggregation operations are a [**cursor**](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/release-notes/2.6/#aggregation-operations-now-return-cursors), so you can iterate that like a `.find()`.

Also introduced in **2.6** is the [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size) operator which is used to find the size of an array in the document. So this would help to remove the second `$unwind` and `$group` that are used in order to get the length of the set. This alters the query to a faster form:

```js
db.sample.aggregate([
    {$group: { 
        _id: "$name",
        comp: {
            $addToSet: { 
                name:"$name",
                type: "$type"
            }
        } 
    }},
    {$project: { 
        comp: 1,
        count: {$size: "$comp"} 
    }},
    {$match: {count: {$gt: 1}}},
    {$unwind: "$comp"},
    {$project: { _id: 0, name: "$comp.name", type: "$comp.type"}}
])
```

And MongoDB 2.6.0-rc0 is currently available if you are doing this just for personal use, or development/testing.

---

Moral of the story. Yes you **can** do it, *But* do you **really** want or *need* to do it that way? Then probably not, and if you asked a different question about the specific business case, you may get a different answer. But then again this may be exactly right for what you want.

### Note

Worthwhile to mention that when you look at the results from the SQL, it will erroneously **duplicate** several items due to the other available type options if you didn't use a `DISTINCT` for those values or essentially another grouping. But that is the result that was being produced by this process using MongoDB.

### For Alexander

This is the output of the aggregate in the shell from current 2.4.x versions:

```js
{
    "result" : [
            {
                    "name" : "f",
                    "type" : "e"
            },
            {
                    "name" : "z",
                    "type" : "z"
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

So do this to get a var to pass as the argument to the $nor condition in the second find, like this:

```js
var cond = db.sample.aggregate([ .....

db.sample.find({$nor: cond.result })
```

And you should get the same results. Otherwise consult your driver.

Comment: yes, this is what I *really* want to do. I run the first part of the query and got lots of results, too many to copy & paste them in $nor. Can I somehow nest the first query within the second one or should I store the results of the first query in a file?

Comment: Use [.toArray()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) and assign the result to a `var` then substitute that in the `$nor` value of the second query. Basically the approach in a language outside of the shell.

Comment: @AlexanderSerebrenik my bad on that. Used to working in the 2.6 shell. Aggregate will give you an array result for the shell, but you need to play with it a bit to get at the result values. Should be under `results` as a key.

Comment: @AlexanderSerebrenik Added a section of the end to illustrate the response from aggregate to passing into the next query from the shell. Hope that helps.

Comment: @NeilLunn, well impressed. Some stuff there I can study, goes much deeper than my knowledge of MongoDB! fab you got under the hood of the question. Bookmarked. ( Alexandra, I'll stop throwing operators at you  now : )

Comment: @NeilLunn I've made a stupid mistake when running your first query for the first time; now it turns out that the aggregation result exceeds 16MB, so I cannot even proceed further.

Comment: @AlexanderSerebrenik See the edit. Just reverse the logic as shown. But this was my warning on this. We can't do more with your question than solve the idiomatic SQL to Mongo problem. So if this does not suit you, perhaps it's best to do what I pointed to and present your use case in another question for which there might be a better solution, like possible re-modelling. Else if this is just a **one-off** operation, dump the collection to your SQL database and process it there.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very simple aggregation that works to get you the names and their types that occur more than once:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
      { $group: { _id : "$name", 
        count:{$sum:1},
        types:{$addToSet:"$type"}}},
      {$match:{"types.1":{$exists:true}}}
])
```

This works in all versions that support aggregation framework.