# Mongo Query display all documents with matching key values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document structure that looks like this:

```
{
  id: objectId(...),
  addressInfo: Object,
  memberInfo: Object,
  membershipID: ObjectId(...)
}
```

I need to pull all documents that match values on three of the keys: addressInfo, memberInfo, and membershipID. The values of these three keys may be identical across multiple documents.

So far, I have come up with this query:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  {$group: {_id:{membershipID:"$membershipID", membershipID:"$membershipID", addressInfo:"$addressInfo", addressInfo:"$addressInfo", memberInfo: "$memberInfo", memberInfo: "$memberInfo"}, count: {$sum:1}}},
  {$match: {count: {$gt:1}}
)
```

It returns all docs where identical values occur more than once.

I'm relatively inexperienced with mongo querying, so I am wondering if there is a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115296/finding-two-documents-in-mongodb-that-share-a-key-value

Comment: @suzo - did you flag this as duplicate?

Comment: @DavidMakogon: yes I did.